# I want to prove that $\text{Sh}(C_{\mathbb{T}},J)$ is the classifing topos for the theory of $\mathbb{T}$-local algebras.

Tags: reference-request, logic, category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

Let $\mathbb{T}$ be a essentially algebraic theory, $C_{\mathbb{T}}$ be its syntactic category and $J$ be a subcanonical coverage on $C_{\mathbb{T}}$

Then, I want to understand why "$\text{Sh}(C_{\mathbb{T}},J)$ is the classifing topos for the geometric theory of $\mathbb{T}$-local algebras."([nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+algebra-ed+topos))

Where should I start from?

I know the definition of geometric theory, essential algebraic theory, subcanonical coverage, grothendieck topos, etc... but don't know how to construct "geometric theory of $\mathbb{T}$-local algebras" and why $C_{\mathbb{T}} \simeq \mathbb{T}\text{Alg}^{\text{fp}}$ holds. I'm unfamiliar with syntactic category.

Could you recommend some literature?

Comment: This is all just a matter of definitions. Why not consult a proper textbook? The nLab is not written as a coherent monograph, after all.

Comment: I don't know textbooks on this. Would you tell me one or two?

Comment: You could look at Part D of [Johnstone, _Sketches of an elephant_], for example.